# I am using PyQt6 for python to make a GUI and I want to have a progress bar on the same window as the main window, but doing so freezes my program

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

The problem is that when I try and run the code, the window and the progress bar load properly, but as soon as I start the "hard work" in the separate thread, it immediately locks up the main window. The problem function is def : save database, which is where the thread is called for and starts. I am running the latest version of Pyqt6 available.

This is the main program:

```
class WikipediaLinkGetter(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("wikipediaGui.ui",self)
    self.setWindowTitle("Wikipedia Link Getter")
    self.tryWikipediaSearchButton.clicked.connect(self.searchWikipedia)
    self.saveDirectoryButton.clicked.connect(self.browseFiles)
    self.saveFilesButton.clicked.connect(self.saveDatabase)

def browseFiles(self):
    home_dir = str(os.getcwd())
    fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Directory', home_dir)
    self.filePathLabel.setText(fname)
    self.filePathLabel.setToolTip(fname)

def saveDatabase(self):
    numLinks = self.links.__sizeof__()
    print(numLinks)
    self.progressBar.setRange(0, numLinks)
    self.thread = TaskThread(copy.deepcopy(self.links),copy.deepcopy(self.filePathLabel.text()))
    self.thread.moveToThread(self.thread)
    self.thread.started.connect(self.thread.run())
    self.thread.progress.connect(self.progressBarUp)
    self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
    self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

    self.thread.start()

def progressBarUp(self,num):
    self.progressBar.setValue(num)

def searchWikipedia(self):
    self.listOfLinksBox.clear()
    searchText = self.searchTerm.text()
    print(searchText)
    self.isComplete = False
    self.links = []
    summary = ''
    firstAttempt = True
    while not self.isComplete:
        try:
            if firstAttempt:
                firstAttempt = False
                page = wikipedia.page(searchText,auto_suggest=False)
                self.isComplete = True
            else:
                self.isComplete = True
                self.disambigApp.exec()
                searchText = self.disambigApp.searchText
                page = wikipedia.page(searchText)
            if isinstance(page,wikipedia.WikipediaPage):
                summary = page.title+': ' +page.summary
                self.links = page.links
        except SystemExit:
            print("Exited")
            self.isComplete = False
            firstAttempt = True
        except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as e:
            print("DisambigError: "+ searchText)
            print(e)
            newPages = e.options
            self.disambigApp = DisambiguationPage(newPages, parent=self)
            self.isComplete = False
        except wikipedia.exceptions.WikipediaException:
            print("SearchIsBusy")
            self.isComplete = False
            firstAttempt = True
    for i in self.links:
        self.listOfLinksBox.addItem(i)
    self.summaryTextBox.setText(summary)
```

This is the class referenced by the above when a disambiguation is needed for the Wikipedia search

```
class DisambiguationPage(QDialog):
def __init__(self, otherPages, parent = None):
    self.pagesDict = {}
    self.searchText = "Apple"
    self.complete = False
    super().__init__(parent)
    uic.loadUi("disambiguationPage.ui",self)
    self.select.clicked.connect(self.buttonPressed)
    for i in otherPages:
        self.pagesDict[i]=QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_7)
        self.pagesDict[i].setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 20))
        self.pagesDict[i].setText(i)
        self.pagesDict[i].setObjectName(i)
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pagesDict[i])

def buttonPressed(self):
    for i in self.pagesDict:
        if self.pagesDict[i].isChecked():
            self.searchText = i
            self.complete=True
            self.accept()
    self.reject()
```

and then the part of the code that does the "hard work" in a separate thread.

```
class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
finished = pyqtSignal()
progress = pyqtSignal(int)
def __init__(self,links,filePath):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self,parent=None)
    self.links = links
    self.filePath = filePath
def run(self):
    directoryPath = self.filePath
    summaryPath = directoryPath + "/summary"
    imagesPath = directoryPath + "/images"
    fullPagePath = directoryPath + "/fullPage"
    if not os.path.exists(summaryPath):
        os.mkdir(summaryPath)
    if not os.path.exists(imagesPath):
        os.mkdir(imagesPath)
    if not os.path.exists(fullPagePath):
        os.mkdir(fullPagePath)
    num = 0
    for i in self.links:
        page = wikipedia.page(i)
        summary = page.summary
        images = page.images
        fullPage = page.content
        tempSummaryPath = summaryPath + '/' + i
        tempImagesPath = imagesPath + '/' + i
        tempFullPagePath = fullPagePath + '/' + i
        with open(tempSummaryPath,'w') as f:
            f.write(summary)
            f.close()
            num += 1
            self.progress.emit(num)
```

and then the main call that starts the program

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = WikipediaLinkGetter()
myApp.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except SystemExit:
    print("Exited")
```

Comment: And where are you creating and starting the `TaskThread`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante, I edited to provide the info, sorry I thought that I had included it in the first place, the code above should be runnable as well. Thank you

Comment: TYPO: `connect(self.thread.run())` -> `connect(self.thread.run)`. But that line should be removed, since `thread.start()` automatically calls `thread.run()` anyway. Also, you should never move a QThread to itself, so remove that line as well. (The deepcopy stuff can also be removed, since it serves no useful purpose).

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you so much, that fixed the code, the only thing that I'm wondering now is where should I move the thread to? If I move the thread to itself the program works as designed, but if I shouldn't do that where should I move it? I think I got the idea from a Qthread tutorial. Thanks so much.

Comment: It doesn't need to be moved anywhere. It's just a wrapper class that manages a system thread, not an actual thread itself. That tutorial you followed sounds out-dated. See: [QThread: You were not doing so wrong](https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html) (but ignore the last part about QtConcurrent). A more detailed overview can be found in the Qt docs: [Threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html).

Comment: @EvanLazzaro is possible use Python's native threading and not QThread. I've not had problems using Qt with python's native threading.